# Adding tag to a question on Chrome for Android: unclear when typing an entire tag text whether the tag already exists

Tags: discussion, tags, mobile-chrome

When adding tag to a question on Chrome for Android, it is unclear after typing an entire tag text whether the tag already exists.

For example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The user can't see from the UI that the tag drink exists whereas the tag drinkk doesn't.

Comment: FWIW: same thing with latest Opera on Android 9.